# Compiler warnings are not showing in basic4andriod ide

Tags: basic4android

my log in the IDE is not working well. i cant see synthax errors, warnings etc.

here is a screenshot

[The first circled area is a sample synthax error that is supposed to produce warnings in the log window circled to the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZtyu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from Release to Debug mode